# Meteor JS behind a proxy

Tags: meteor, proxy

I'm trying to use Meteor from behind a proxy. I've tried setting environment variables for proxy details as the docs but it has not helped.

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
meteor update
```

Instead I want to bypass the proxy for the certain URLs that Meteor needs. I have identified [atmospherejs.com](http://atmospherejs.com) and [registry.npmjs.org](http://registry.npmjs.org) (not sure if meteor uses this directly but we are also working with node separately).

Are there any other URLs that Meteor will need?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some:

```
docs.meteor.com
s3-1.amazonaws.com
activity.meteor.com
warehouse.meteor.com
registry.npmjs.org
registry.npmjs.org
packages.meteor.com
```

I can't imagine that it's a specific domain causing your problem tough.